# How to run a command at a specific time using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timer, whenever

I've created a Rails app that sends a push notification to a mobile device; I would like the user to be able to choose a time to be sent the notification, like an alarm. I've looked into the Whenever gem but it seems that the app needs to be updated whenever the desired time also changes. The desired time could change at anytime depending on the user's preference.

Answer (score 1):

I would think about two different approaches:

**Cron**: You could have a cron task that starts a Rails method with `script/runner "PushNotifier.perform"` every x minutes. In that method you check for users that need to be notified since the last run.

- *Pro*: Cron is very reliable and available on every Linux box.
- *Con*: What happens if your tasks takes longer than the cron interval? You have to think about problems like that. Scaling might be a challenge.

**Delayed Job**: You could create a scheduled DelayedJob for every user that wants to have a notification. If the DelayedJob is performed it tests if it is still a thing to run (did the user cancel in between?). Sends the notification and adds an other job to the queue for the next recurring notification.

- *Pro*: Should scale pretty well, even with multiple servers handling hundreds of notifications at the same time.
- *Con*: You need to setup, maintain and monitor any other piece of software to your stack.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, such timings are controlled by applications specific to the task — not a rails app:

- [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)
- [launchctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html)

Since you probalby won't run OSX for any prod environment stuff, Launchctl is just an example of a great scheduling system.

With cron, you can run your rails app (or a small secondary rails app / sinatra) via  user that has access to shell-out to `crontab -e` and add new entries.  Code like [CronEdit](http://rubydoc.info/gems/cronedit/0.3.0/CronEdit) will let you do that in Ruby

---

#### System utilities, like Cron, are simple and reliable.  They run with tiny CPU and Memory footprints, and are long-vetted for reliability.  They are a better production solution than a rails app.